# Python-telegram-bot: RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop

Tags: python-asyncio, python-telegram-bot

I developed a small Telegram Bot in Python and updated it from v13 to v20 and now I'm facing issues with the async methods.

The errors that I received are `RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop` and `RuntimeError: This event loop is already running`

To try to tackle down the issue, I started over from scratch using the basic example from PTB, but I still got the error.

Here is my code:

```
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, ContextTypes, CommandHandler

mytoken = 'here_my_token'

logging.basicConfig(
    format='$(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_messsage(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Welcome to my bot, please say something!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(mytoken).build()
    
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    
    application.run_polling()
```

The traceback I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py:946 in __run
    raise exc

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py:935 in __run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.initialize())

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:625 in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:584 in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py:957 in __run
    loop.run_until_complete(self.shutdown())

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:625 in run_until_complete
    self._check_running()

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:584 in _check_running
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')

RuntimeError: This event loop is already running


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[1], line 21
    application.run_polling()

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py:752 in run_polling
    return self.__run(

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/telegram/ext/_application.py:962 in __run
    loop.close()

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/asyncio/unix_events.py:68 in close
    super().close()

  File /home/anaconda3/envs/working_env/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py:84 in close
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot close a running event loop")

RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CallbackContext, CommandHandler

mytoken = 'here_my_token'

logging.basicConfig(
    format='$(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)

async def start(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Welcome to my bot, please say something!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = ApplicationBuilder().token(mytoken).build()
    
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    
    application.run_polling()
```

I found a couple of errors in your code:

Typo in send_message: The function name send_messsage has an extra "s" in it. It should be send_message.

Incorrect ContextType: In the start function, you are using ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE as the type for the context parameter. However, the correct type for the context parameter in CommandHandler is CallbackContext. Change ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE to CallbackContext.

Comment: Thanks! Those errors are a bit stupid on my side. I also found out that the issue had to do with Spyder. With importing nest_asyncio the issue was fixed